# Strange error saving and loading PyTorch model from jupyter notebook

Tags: file-io, path, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, save

I am trying to train a ConvNet using PyTorch. I would like to save and reload my model. I am writing my code in a Jupyter notebook.

I am encountering a very strange error that I have not been able to find online.

When I save and load my model using

```
torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, 'checkpoint.pth.tar')
```

and

```
checkpoint = torch.load('checkpoint.pth.tar')
```

everything works fine.

However, if I try to save  or load to a different directory, for example

```
torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, 'model_checkpoints/checkpoint.pth.tar')
```

or

```
checkpoint = torch.load('model_checkpoints/checkpoint.pth.tar')
```

I get the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-4afed4ac9dc5> in <module>
----> 1 checkpoint = torch.load('model_checkpoints/checkpoint.pth.tar')

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\envs\streetview\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    569         pickle_load_args['encoding'] = 'utf-8'
    570 
--> 571     with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
    572         if _is_zipfile(opened_file):
    573             # The zipfile reader is going to advance the current file position.

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\envs\streetview\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in _open_file_like(name_or_buffer, mode)
    227 def _open_file_like(name_or_buffer, mode):
    228     if _is_path(name_or_buffer):
--> 229         return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
    230     else:
    231         if 'w' in mode:

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda3\envs\streetview\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py in __init__(self, name, mode)
    208 class _open_file(_opener):
    209     def __init__(self, name, mode):
--> 210         super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
    211 
    212     def __exit__(self, *args):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model_checkpoints/checkpoint.pth.tar'
```

This problem is occurring even though such a directory and file do exist! For example, I have double and triple checked that I am not misspelling the name of model_checkpoints, and I saved a checkpoint using the method that works and then manually moved it into model_checkpoints.

I am at my wits ends and would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried running a bare-bones script that just creates a model, saves it, and then instantly reloads it (all within the correct folder)? This will remove any chance directory changes or other potential issues.